# Namespace issue with SimpleXmlElement

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I have a problem with SimpleXMLElement.
I have to create a XML as here:

```
<p:father>
  <child></child>
</p:father>
```

If I try to do this with SimpleXMLElement result is:

```
<p:father>
  <p:child></p:child>
</p:father>
```

So all children have the same namespace. PHP code is:

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement('<p:father xmlns:p="http://example.com" />');
$xml->addChild('child');
```

Can anyone help me? I have to do this in order to create xml for Eletronical Invoicing.

Comment: _“So all children have the same namespace.”_ - can’t reproduce, your code results in `<child/>` across all PHP versions, see https://3v4l.org/lpt4g (But the warnings shown there already suggest that you are not currently handling creation of a namespaced element correctly to begin with.)

Comment: I have to do an XML that has this format. https://3v4l.org/HEdB3

Comment: Hi, I've [edit]ed your question to include a [mcve] - a piece of code that someone can actually run to reproduce your problem. Please try to do this in future questions, as your previous example was not valid XML, leaving people to guess what you were actually doing.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here seems to be that you are mixing namespaced elements with non-namespaced elements: you give a namespace the prefix `p:`, but don't set any default namespace for non-prefixed elements. SimpleXML seems to be "helpfully" setting your child element to be in the `p:` namespace rather than in no namespace at all.

The cleanest solution I can find is to define a namespace URI for your unprefixed elements, and then passing that to the `addChild` call:

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement('<p:father xmlns:p="http://example.com/prefixed" xmlns="http://example.com/default" />');
$xml->addChild('child', null, 'http://example.com/default');
echo $xml->asXML();
```

Which results in:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> <p:father xmlns:p="http://example.com/prefixed" xmlns="http://example.com/default"><child/></p:father>
```